# png image does not get embedded in HTML output

Tags: ruby, cucumber

I changed the html "formatter" to embed my image using the following code:

```
@builder.div(:id => 'image') do
   @builder << '<div style="float:center";><img SRC="/home/abc/cert-image.png" ALT="Image"> </div>'
 end
```

The HTML file has the following tag but there is no encoded image inside the HTML page.

```
div id="image"><div style="float:center";><img SRC="/home/abc/cert-image.png" ALT="Image">
```

Now if I open this in a browser (Chrome), it does not show me the image. If I change this path above on my local laptop and point to an image, it works (i.e displays it correctly).

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/home/abc/cert-image.png` is a relative path from your HTML file. Nothing is wrong with the html or the formatter, but your path is likely wrong.

Try clicking where the image should be and opening the URL to the image in a new window. That will give you the absolute URL to where the img tag is pointing, and you can fix/debug from there.

**EDIT**

Ignore that, I found the error in your formatter:

```
@builder.div(:id => 'image') do
  @builder << '<div style="float:center;"><img SRC="/home/abc/cert-image.png" ALT="Image" /> </div>'
end
```

**EDIT 2**

Since you just want to base64 encode the image with a data uri, you can do this:

```
require 'base64'

file = File.open("/home/abc/cert-image.png", "rb").read
b64 = Base64.encode64(file)
```

Then in your formatter:

```
@builder.div(:id => 'image') do
  @builder << '<div style="float:center;"><img SRC="data:image/png;base64,' + b64 + '" ALT="Image" /> </div>'
end
```

Comment: Thanks. But my real issue is still how to embed inline image inside the data url. The image is very small so it makes sense to embed it (base64?)....I've not done this before so any help would be great.

Comment: Oh. You have to say that in your question!

Comment: Sorry about that confusion. I agree - could have been more clear in my question. Please help.

Comment: So how would my formatter code look after I get "base64" gem. Would my SRC be pointing to b64 ? i.e.

Comment: Yeah, just put the base64 string in the src, with ```data:image/png;base64,``` before it.